# How to copy a ImageField without reupload and resave it?

Tags: django, django-imagekit

I have a ImageField, when user create the first post, it put a image to S3, when another user redo on it(just like Pinterest's repin), I need copy the image.name to the new, but do not need upload an resave the image, how can I do it?

Answer (score 3):

If you do not want to Upload your image again and Just want to keep file with new name then you can use PUT Object COPY Request 
Please go through the following link url ->>
http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectCOPY.html

You won't need to reupload the new copy using this command

Comment: I just need create a database record, it's include the orginal record's field image_url, not need copy the image itself, but how to do it in django?